# Modify errors in Redux-form from 'outside'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I got a random component with Redux-form, e.g.:

```
{code...}

  <form>
    <Field
      component={TextField}
      name="firstName"
    />
  </form>

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm',
  validate,
})(injectIntl(myForm)));
```

And a `validate.js` file:

```
{code...}

const firstName = trim(values.get('firstName'));
if (!(firstName)) {
  errors.firstName = 'Required';
}
```

**Im able to modify** the error message, it can be *Required*, or anything else I want.

**But my question is**: am I able to change the error or even add a new one condition but **outside** the `validate.js` file? For example inside the component. So I could change the *Required* name to another one, without modifying the `validate.js` file?

Thanks!

**Edit**: How can I reference to specified field in the component holding the form?

Is there a way to fix it globally? Simple example:

`globalComponent.js`

```
{ 
   form: 'myForm',
   error: {
     field: 'firstName',
     errorMsg: 'Use a capital letter!',
   },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate object to define the validation messages:

```
export const validationMessages = {
    required: 'Field is required'
}

// ...code

errors.firstName = validationMessages.required
```

Then, if you need to change the messages for required, just set the validationMessages.required, like this:

```
validationMessages.required = 'First name is required'
```

However, mutate an object with the validation messages isn't a good solution. I strongly recommend you to use a module called [redux-form-validators](https://github.com/gtournie/redux-form-validators).

With this module, you can easily override the validation message:

```
import { required, email } from 'redux-form-validators'

<Field
  ...
  validate={required()} // Will use the default required message
>

<Field
  ...
  validate={required({ message: 'Hey, the first name is required!' })} // Will override the default message
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im looking for a different solution, my error comes from API, e.g. 'First name already taken' so I need to be able to somehow inject it into the field.

Comment: Did you try [SubmissionError](http://redux-form.com/7.0.4/docs/api/SubmissionError.md/)? It will automatically inject the errors into the field specified by the server.